Prevent LLDB step into xstring and other MSVC files
When I debug my project using CLion lldb debugger (built-in version 9.0), lldb keeps stepping into c++ standard files such as xstring in MSVC include folder (std::basic_string::basic_string<…>(const std::string &) xstring:698).
I tried using this command in .lldbinit file
settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ^(std::|std::basic_string::).*

but this doesn't prevent this.
I already checked to ensure .lldbinit is used by the debugger using
settings show target.process.thread

to check target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp value is as I set.
Is there any way to resolve this issue?
I am using CLion and Windows 11 and MSVC compiler.

Probably best to file this as a bug with https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.  Start a debug session and get to the point where the next step is going to go wrong.  Then turn on the step log: log enable -f /tmp/lldb-log.txt lldb step.  Also, run the disassemble and the source info -f <filename-stepping-from>.   Then do the step, and file a but with the command output and the lldb-log.txt file.
